# How to find the highest disk space usage mount?

Tags: linux, mount

I'm looking for a command where only the highest disk space usage mount will be shown. So The maximum %usage mount will be shown.

Running `df -h`

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vx/dsk/appdg/boom-vol
                      1.0G   19M  943M   2% /opt/blah99
                      500G  349G  152G  70% /opt/blah/data
/dev/vx/dsk/isdg/boom-shared-vol
                       50G  1.6G   46G   4% /opt/blah99/product/shared
/dev/vx/dsk/isdg/boom-bc-vol
                      150G   64G   81G  45% /opt/blah99/product/a_01
/dev/vx/dsk/isdg/boom-bt-vol
                      150G   47G   98G  33% /opt/blah99/product/a_02
```

Output should be -

```
                      500G  349G  152G  70% /opt/blah/data
```

Comment: If you're looking for "a command" then you should probably be asking on Superuser (but you probably won't have any luck). If you want to write some code to do that, then you should have an attempt (which would involve such as things choosing a programming language) and then ask here if you have a more specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

```
df -h | grep -vw "^\/dev" | sort -k 5 -n | tail -n 2 | head -n 1
```

Output of `df -h | grep -vw "^\/dev"`:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
                      1.0G   19M  943M   2% /opt/blah99
                      500G  349G  152G  70% /opt/blah/data
                       50G  1.6G   46G   4% /opt/blah99/product/shared
                      150G   64G   81G  45% /opt/blah99/product/a_01
                      150G   47G   98G  33% /opt/blah99/product/a_02
```

Sorting by column 5 in numeric order: `df -h | grep -vw "^\/dev" | sort -k 5 -n`:

```
                       50G  1.6G   46G   4% /opt/blah99/product/shared
                      1.0G   19M  943M   2% /opt/blah99
                      150G   47G   98G  33% /opt/blah99/product/a_02
                      150G   64G   81G  45% /opt/blah99/product/a_01
                      500G  349G  152G  70% /opt/blah/data
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
```

Getting second row from the end: `df -h | grep -vw "^\/dev" | sort -k 5 -n | tail -n 2 | head -n 1`:

```
                  500G  349G  152G  70% /opt/blah/data
```

Comment: You understood me correctly. But somehow the command you have given is not giving me the correct output.

Comment: Posted in question.